# Adding comment within a function in kernel makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu

Suppose there is a function like below in kernel makefile.

```
define rule_vmlinux__
        :
        $(if $(CONFIG_KALLSYMS),,+$(call cmd,vmlinux_version))

        $(call cmd,vmlinux__)
        $(Q)echo 'cmd_$@ := $(cmd_vmlinux__)' > $(@D)/.$(@F).cmd

        $(Q)$(if $($(quiet)cmd_sysmap),                                      \
          echo '  $($(quiet)cmd_sysmap)  System.map' &&)                     \
        $(cmd_sysmap) $@ System.map;                                         \
        if [ $$? -ne 0 ]; then                                               \
                rm -f $@;                                                    \
                /bin/false;                                                  \
        fi;
        $(verify_kallsyms)

        $(Q)$(if $($(quiet)cmd_arm1136_cid_scan),                            \
          echo '  $($(quiet)cmd_arm1136_cid_scan)' &&)                       \
          $(cmd_arm1136_cid_scan)
endef
```

I want to comment something inside this function (say `$(verify_kallsyms)`).I have tried with `pound(#)` and `@` but it does not work. I got the below sentence from gnu manual:

> You cannot use comments within variable references or function calls:
>   any instance of # will be treated literally (rather than as the start
>   of a comment) inside a variable reference or function call.

Is it possible to add comment or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use comments to disable code, you have to define a new function `opt_verify_kallsyms`. Use a flag to control the body of the function. If the flag is not set, make the new function expand to `$(verify_kallsyms)`. If the flag is set, make it expand to nothing.